# Do native speakers pronounce "z" as or close to "s"?

Tags: pronunciation, dialect

Sometimes I hear English speakers pronounce "z" very close to "s" in some words. I wonder if it's common, from a dialect, mispronounced, or just I misheard it. For example, "zero" sounds like "sero" and "citizen" sounds like "citisen". Is that acceptable, or in no case should it happen?

Comment: Where did you hear this? Where I live (SE USA), the z is very distinct in **zero**.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Sorry I couldn't remember where, maybe even from online videos or phone calls. I did sometimes hear people pronounce "z" nearly voiceless while my pronunciation is obviously voiced. So I was always wondering if my pronunciation was "over-voiced". But I don't have an example video for now.

Comment: For "citizen", yes, I could imagine hearing it pronounced close to "cisisen". As for "zero", in the right context, like, "It's zero", where the "s" before it creates a voiceless environment, "zero" might be pronounced closer to "sero". But without that environment, like in, "The answer is zero" where the "-s"  is pronounced "z", only a non-native speaker would pronounce it "sero".

Comment: @FeliniusRex Yes, same in my part of South England, the "z" on zero is pronounced very differently from "s". Also "citi**zn**" is the usual pronunciation round here. This is based on "Received pronunciation" or RP.

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciations are usually distinct. For example, "doze" and "dose" are usually distinguished pretty easily.

A few caveats:

- I live in the U.S. Northeast. Pronunciations in other regions might vary.
- Some instances of "z" are not voiced. This is normal, for example, after "t" (spritz, putz, spitz, etc.). However, such instances are somewhat rare.
- The reverse is not true; "s" is often voiced. But that's another issue.